# displays duplicate records in dropdown(basically executes data from previus http calls)

Tags: android

I am  trying to execute search friends like facebook in my app .But the data repeats/duplicates and displays onTextchanged when typed quickly.

How do I stop data from repeating also how do I refresh list and adapter and drop-down with new values?I have tried many possible ways but the data is still repeating please offer me a solution.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

baseActivity

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader ;
    Bitmap image;
    private DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;

    public SimpleAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity)
        .threadPoolSize(2) 
        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .build();

        imageLoader  = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.init(config);

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get("firstname"));
        artist.setText(song.get("lastname")); 
        duration.setText(song.get("time"));
        imageLoader.displayImage(song.get("link"), thumb_image, defaultOptions);

        return vi;
    }


}
```

Mainactivity

```
public class AutoCompleteTextViewActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private TextView selection;
        private AutoCompleteTextView actv;


        SimpleAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
           actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv);
           actv.addTextChangedListener(this);



        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Suggest Suggestdetails=new Suggest();
         if(aList!=null){

          Suggestdetails.execute(); 
         aList.clear();
          } else{

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

 }


        }

        public class Suggest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

                 String ResponseBody = null;

                try {


                    //geoaddress here 

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/suggest.php");

                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", actv.getText().toString()));


                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    String result = sb.toString();

                    Log.d("Fb tr",result);
                    // parsing data
                    return new JSONObject(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {




                if (result != null) {
                    // do something
    //              JSONObject tr = result;

            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                try{
                  JSONArray arr=result.getJSONArray("Array");


                for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject json= (JSONObject) e1.get("data");

                    String firstname = json.getString("firstname").trim();  
                    String lastname = json.getString("lastname").trim();
                    String link = json.getString("link").trim();
                    String time = json.getString("time").trim();


                     HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        hm.put("firstname", firstname);
                        hm.put("lastname", lastname );
                        hm.put("link", link);
                        hm.put("time", time);
                        aList.add(hm);

                    }


                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                String[] from = { "firstname","lastname","time","link"};


                int[] to = { R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.list_image};

                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AutoCompleteTextViewActivity.this,aList, R.layout.list_row,from,to);

                   actv.setAdapter(adapter);

                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } else {
                    // error occured
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: from your code I don't see any reason for duplicate values in the list. are you sure the server does not create the duplicate values ?

Comment: no .I am using `like` statement .Here `Select * from table where name like "$text%"` . Please let me know what I am doing wrong? I really appreciate your time and effort to look into it.Thanks.

Comment: from `actv.setAdapter(adapter);` and `List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();` in onPostExecute, the duplication of the data cannot come from that part. I would start by looking into the values obtained in `result` from your php script.

Comment: I check it again .THe json response is perfect but if I type data in autocompletetextview quickly then the previous data overlaps current data.I think the http response from previous is add on top of current one hence I see 2 datasets but his happens only if I type quickly but if I type letter by letter it works perfectly.